# Does Nextjs dynamic import without SSR has supported React.Lazy?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a question that needs to be answered. I am implementing Dynamic import with option `{ ssr: false }`:

```
const MyComponent = dynamic(() => import('./my-component'), { ssr: false })
```

I wonder if it has the feature React.lazy integrated or not?

Comment: `next/dynamic` is an extension of `React.lazy`, as per the docs.

Answer (score 0):

According [nextjs docs:](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr)

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicHeader = dynamic(() => import('../components/header'), {
  ssr: false,
})
```

Comment: Nextjs used this option for disable server-rendering, but does it including React.lazy ? Or does we have to do it manually?

Comment: `next/dynamic` is an extension of `React.lazy`.